# Copy tags to copied django object

Tags: django, django-taggit, deep-copy

I'm using [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) to tag my to do records.

```
class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Action Name", max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Complete?")

    tags = TaggableManager()
```

I'm trying to make an exact copy of a records, down to the tags that are associated with the task.

```
new_obj = deepcopy(self)
new_obj.id = None
new_obj.save()
```

After running this code, the copy is exact except that there are no affiliated tags.  How can I copy all of the tags from "self" to new_obj?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding the tags to the object:

```
new_obj.tags.add(tag)
```

I added the new object to the Tag:

```
for tag in self.tags.all():
    tag_object = TaggedItem(content_object = new_obj, tag = tag)
    tag_object.save()
```